# How to install React Native for android app development on Windows platform?

Tags: android, react-native

I want to start using React Native for developing Android apps. I would like to know how do I install React Native on my computer to develop Android Apps?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html here you can

Comment: follow this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Answer (score 0):

First you need to download and then install [Node js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). Then you can use npm to install the create-react-native-app command line utility: `npm install -g create-react-native-app`

Then run the following commands to create a new React Native project called "AwesomeProject":

```
create-react-native-app AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject
npm start
```

Here AwesomeProject is the project name of yours. `cd AwesomeProject` command to enter the project folder. And `npm start` command is used to create a development server.

Hope this help

[Doucmentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 0):

nkyou can install and start reactnative project using [this link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started)
first you should choose  *Building Projects with Native Code* and then choose windows and android to find how you can install.